# Paging data is refreshing on navigation in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-paging

I'm getting some data from my database like this

```kotlin
Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = PAGE_SIZE)) {
        songRepo.getSongs()
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

and I collect it in the UI using `collectAsLazyPagingItems()`, but whenever I navigate to another screen and I go back the data is clearing.
Is there a solution to this or I should create my own pagination without Paging?

Comment: Are you creating new Pager instance every time or do you store it in your ViewModel?

Comment: No just one instance

Comment: How is your viewmodel created?

Comment: with dagger hilt

Comment: Why do you need `viewModel.setSongs(songs)`?

Comment: I don't use `LazyPagingItems` directly from `collectAsLazyPagingItems` I store it in the view model then I use it from there so I can avoid the data refreshing

Comment: `.cachedIn(viewModelScope)` avoid the data refreshing and this is enough if the view model is the same

Comment: I used item element before `LazyPagingItems` items and that's the reason. This is a bug in the package issue's link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179397301

Comment: from comments: "any item outside of the items from the paging library will cause the scroll position to be lost." - it is real reason, [temporary solution](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177245496#comment24) worked. Also `state.songs?.let` is unnecessary

Answer (score -2):

You will have to create a new instance of Pager every time you come back from a new screen.

```
Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = PAGE_SIZE)) {
   songRepo.getSongs("albumId",false )
 }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Comment: Still the same issue